# How to append multiple lines of text to a file?

Tags: command-line, text

I want to append this text:

```
<Directory "/var/www/*">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

I have access via SSH but I don't know how to use VIM. I would like to do this via a command.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you use nano?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

(you may need to use `sudo`)

This will give you a command line text editor that works much like normal text editors. Use the arrow keys to navigate. Backspace, enter, etc. work as normal.

To save, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. For help, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> from inside nano, or use [`man nano`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nano).

It should look something like this:

[image: nano]

Answer (score 18):

This syntax is called "HERE documents":

```
sudo tee -a /tmp/file <<EOF
<Directory "/var/www/*">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>    
EOF
```

This solution is better than using ctrl-d since it can be used inside shell scripts.

Comment: I would agree with 'for use inside shell scripts, you will want to use HERE document syntax' .

Comment: btw, sometimes ctrl-d doesn't work. I once had to paste something in a file from a xen console running a initrd shell with incomplete terminal support; ctrl-c, ctrl-d etc didn't work, so I had to resort to HERO document also interactively.

Comment: That `cat` is completely useless, just the `tee` is enough. `sudo tee -a /tmp/file << EOF`.

Comment: yes, `cat` is often abused

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way to do it, using `cat` .

```
% cat - >> testf
one
two
   three
four
```

You terminate your input with the <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> .

This takes interactive input from `cat` (i.e., whatever you type in), and appends it to the existing file `testf` .

`testf` (with two original lines intact) will now look like this:

```
original line 1
original line 2

one
two
   three
four
```

As other answers have illustrated, you will need special syntax when editing files which you don't have write permission on.   I find it easier to just switch to the root user for this, i.e., `sudo su` .   But another easy method is to use `tee` with the append flag set, and called with `sudo`:

`sudo tee -a >> config.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The `nano` editor is more friendly (`sudo apt-get install nano` if not available).

```
echo "<Directory \"/var/www/*\">"  > out_file
echo "    Order allow,deny"       >> out_file
echo "    Allow from all"         >> out_file
echo "    AllowOverride All"      >> out_file
echo "</Directory>"               >> out_file

cat out_file | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: You should make a backup first when blindly editing like this - it is very easy to mistype something and end up clobbering the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a Vim, here is the command to run:

```
sudo vim -e +'$put = \"<Directory \\"/var/www/*\\">\n\tOrder allow,deny\n\tAllow from all\n\tAllowOverride All\n</Directory>\n\"' -cwq /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

If you don't have `vim`, this is also equivalent to either `vi -e` or `ex`.

Alternative cleaner approach:

```
$ sudo ex +"r /dev/stdin" -cwq output.txt <<-EOF
<Directory "/var/www/*">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
EOF
```

Just run the first line (without `$`), paste the multi line text, then type `EOF` to finish.